# How to reduce the lag in my paint application on android

Tags: java, android

I have been making a paint app for android with the ability to choose different colors. 
my task is almost complete. yet there is cetain lag in my app. At start it works fine but after some lines it starts giving straight lines instead of curves and lags in usage....

This is the code for my DrawIt:

```
package app.paintit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
public class DrawIt extends View{
    float x,y;
    Paint paint;
    int count1=0,count2=0;
    ArrayList<Lines> lines = new ArrayList<Lines>();
    public int color= 0xFFFFFF;
    Lines l;
    Path path;
    public DrawIt(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    x=0;y=0;
    paint=new Paint();
    path = new Path();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                l = new Lines();
                l.color  = color;
                l.xCoordinate = new ArrayList<Float>();
                l.xCoordinate.add(event.getX());
                l.yCoordinate = new ArrayList<Float>();
                l.yCoordinate.add(event.getY());
                lines.add(l);

            }

            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {

                l.color = color;
                l.xCoordinate.add(event.getX());
                l.yCoordinate.add(event.getY());
                lines.add(l);


            }

            invalidate();   


            return true;

        }
    });

    }



    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        Lines p,q;
        float nowX,nowY,prevX=0,prevY=0;

        for(int j=0;j<lines.size();j++){
            p = lines.get(j);
            Path path1=new Path();
            paint.setColor(p.color);
            path1.moveTo(p.xCoordinate.get(0), p.yCoordinate.get(0));
            for(int i=1;i<p.xCoordinate.size()-1;i++){

                float midX=(p.xCoordinate.get(i)+p.xCoordinate.get(i-1))/2;
                float midY=(p.yCoordinate.get(i)+p.yCoordinate.get(i-1))/2;
                path1.quadTo(p.xCoordinate.get(i-1), p.yCoordinate.get(i-1), midX, midY);


            canvas.drawPath(path1, paint); 

        }

    }
}
}
```

The code for Lines.java which holds the lists that help in maintaining different colors is :

```
   package app.paintit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import android.graphics.Color;
public class Lines {
ArrayList<Float> xCoordinate;
ArrayList<Float> yCoordinate;
int color;
}
```

Please help me how to reduce the lag and the straight lines happening after some shapes are drawn perfectly.

Comment: Calling invalidate redraws your entire canvas with every line. Eventually this is going to be a lot of crunching for your onDraw method (where your lag is likely occurring).

Comment: I usually put the `invalidate()` in the draw method, and I call `postInvalidateDelayed(15)` to keep the framerate close to constant.